# Ignore all numeric in REGEXP_LIKE

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I am trying to find all records which have anything other than numeric value this includes `alphabets` `charachters`. I need this information to determine what datatype I am going to store the data I get from `SUBSTR(COLUMN1,8,4)` as I am running the following query:

```
select SUBSTR(COLUMN1,8,4)
from tmp_table
where REGEXP_LIKE (SUBSTR(COLUMN1,8,4),'[^0-9\x]+$');
```

The results I get for query are as follows:

```
918 
922S
944 
950N
953 
958S
974 
977A
994A
995
```

I am also adding the query to show input data the query used is:

```
select column1
from tmp_xsttable
where REGEXP_LIKE (SUBSTR(COLUMN1,24,4),'[^0-9\x]+$');
```

The data I got is :

```
AHGLXST912 200701010000912 L000000000000000000NC0000  CA20070216 10     
AHGLXST917 200501020000917 L000000000020071231NC000001CC20090805 10     
AHGLXST918 200501020000918 L000000000020071231NC000001CC20090805 10     
AHGLXST920A200501020000920AL000000000000000000NC000001CA20050130 64     
AHGLXST921 193501010000921 L000000000000000000NH0000  DA20040901 30     
AHGLXST921D193501010000921DL000000000000000000NH0000  DA20040901 30     
AHGLXST922A192501010000922AL000000000000000000NC0000  CA20050311 64     
AHGLXST922G192501010000922GL000000000020081231NC0000  CC20090805 44     
AHGLXST922N200501020000922NL000000000000000000NC0000  CA20050517 74     
AHGLXST922S193501010000922SL000000000000000000NH0000  CA20040901 10
```

Here are some example dataset that is in `Column1` of `tmp_table`:

```
AHGLXST01362007061700530136L000000057000000000YH0005  RA20070619110     
AHGLXST01362011092500540136L000000057000000000YH0005  RA20110927110     
AHGLXST01362014090700950136L000000057000000000YC0009  RA20140909110     
AHGLXST01371973112800670137L000000026000000000YH0008  RC2004052011011   
AHGLXST01372006010100640137L000000026020061005YC0008  RC2006102511011   
AHGLXST01391988040600510139L000000080500000000YH0006  RC2004052021022   
AHGLXST01392007061700550139L000000080520101113YC0005  RC20101214210     
AHGLXST01401997071300560140L000000047400000000YH0006  RC2004052011011   
AHGLXST01402006042900560140L000000047400000000YH0008  RA20060426110     
AHGLXST01402007061700750140L000000047400000000YH0007  RA20070619110
```

I am trying to ignore the records which are numeric but I get these 3 digit results along with the records which have alphabets and characters. How do I change my REGEXP_LIKE to ignore all numeric?

Comment: You need to try again. In the title you say "ignore **whitespace**", then in the first sentence of your post you say "anything other than **numeric value**" and then you have `\x` in the regular expression (in a matching set, where it is not interpreted as a class of characters anyway - you are simply searching for substrings that contain a character that is not a digit, a slash or lower-case 'x'). Show us the **inputs** too, and explain the requirement in plain English rather than code - but in a way that you don't contradict yourself.

Comment: @mathguy Thanks I changed my title the results I showed is a part of results I got the column1 I am quering to get these results is a long varchar2 column I will add example of that in my description. I am searching  in my SUBSTR to see if I have aphabets or characters so that I can choose the datatype I will insert the substr in

Comment: I didn't run the query on the data you just provided, but I don't think it will produce the results you show. It would be much better to include the "defective" rows that you are trying to detect along with the "good" rows in your sample input. What is the issue - for example with 918: do you suspect that in the inputs, the digits 918 are followed by a space, and in that case you don't want them rejected? (They probably SHOULD be rejected, or if you are going to insert numbers, the space should be TRIMMED first.)

Comment: @mathguy I changed the query now theres is example dataset which is good and then I included another query which shows some data that has 3 digit numeric and a space along with records which have 3 digit numeric and 1digit alphabet

Comment: @mathguy the problem with 918 is that it is numeric and what I am looking for is only records with aphabets or characters if its 3 digit or 2 digit but has not alphabets or characters I want to reject them in my select query.

Comment: But in your examples, the substring you are extracting is still FOUR characters long. It is three digits AND A SPACE. And that is why they appear in the output of the query you wrote. If you want to trim spaces from the end (or perhaps from both ends) you can do so by wrapping the `SUBSTR(....)` expression within `TRIM(.....)`, both in `SELECT` and in the `REGEXP_LIKE` condition in the `WHERE` clause

Comment: @mathguy Is there a way to ignore space inside REGEXP_LIKE rather than using TRIM?

Comment: @Auguster Is there a reason you can't just include it in the expression? From what you've shown, it will always be three numbers followed by a space. So something like `\d{3}\s` should work.

Comment: The problem is that you want to insert numbers into a new table. If you allow the strings that are three digits followed by a space to stand, you will be inserting them (WITH THE SPACE) in the new table. That may lead to unexpected results. It would be best if Oracle would reject those inserts with an error message (and then you would ask "what is Oracle complaining about" not realizing that there is an extra space at the end).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing in your query is getting data where `SUBSTR(COLUMN1,8,4)` contains at least one non-numeric character. I think what you want is more like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(column1, 8, 4)
  FROM tmp_table
 WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(SUBSTR(column1, 8, 4), '\d');
```

The above query would return all rows for which the value of `COLUMN1` does not contain a digit in the four characters starting from the 8th position (that is, characters 8-11).

Comment: I don't think it works if value is '123A' it will match '\d' because there is a decimal in it so it will be filtered even though he wants to get exactly these values

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the OP

Comment: Maybe it's me. I thought he wanted `where REGEXP_LIKE (TRIM(SUBSTR(COLUMN1,8,4)),'[^0-9]')`

Comment: @LauDec - the issue seems to be with cases when the four-character substring is three digits followed by space. The OP will have to confirm what he wants to do in that case - perhaps capture just the three digits and call that a number. In that case an additional RTRIM or TRIM seems like the simplest solution.

Comment: @mathguy : from his last paragraph, "I am trying to ignore the records which are numeric but I get these 3 digit results along ..." I personally  understood that he wants to treat them like numerics, i.e ignore them. Thus my solution with the trim. But maybe i'm wrong. he got me a little confused ;)

Comment: @LauDec sorry about confusing request I wanted to ignore all numeric even if they are 3 digit followed by space or 2 digit followed by 2 spaces. I think RTRIM seems like the best way everyone is recommending